# preg_replace gives back empty string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

```
//Chars to be replaced      
$suchmuster = array();
$suchmuster[0] = 'á';
$suchmuster[1] = 'à';
$suchmuster[2] = 'â';

$suchmuster[3] = 'é';
$suchmuster[4] = 'è';
$suchmuster[5] = 'ê';

$suchmuster[6] = 'í';
$suchmuster[7] = 'ì';
$suchmuster[8] = 'î';

$suchmuster[9] = 'ó';
$suchmuster[10] = 'ò';
$suchmuster[11] = '/ô/';

$suchmuster[12] = 'ú';
$suchmuster[13] = 'ù';
$suchmuster[14] = 'û';

$suchmuster[15] = ' ';
$suchmuster[16] = '.';
$suchmuster[17] = ',';
$suchmuster[18] = '-';
$suchmuster[19] = '_';

//Replaces

$ersetzungen = array();
$ersetzungen[0] = 'a';
$ersetzungen[1] = 'a';
$ersetzungen[2] = 'a';

$ersetzungen[3] = 'e';
$ersetzungen[4] = 'e';
$ersetzungen[5] = 'e';

$ersetzungen[6] = 'i';
$ersetzungen[7] = 'i';
$ersetzungen[8] = 'i';

$ersetzungen[9] = 'o';
$ersetzungen[10] = 'o';
$ersetzungen[11] = 'o';

$ersetzungen[12] = 'u';
$ersetzungen[13] = 'u';
$ersetzungen[14] = 'u';

$ersetzungen[15] = '';
$ersetzungen[16] = '';
$ersetzungen[17] = '';
$ersetzungen[18] = '';
$ersetzungen[19] = '';

$newmessage = preg_replace($suchmuster, $ersetzungen, strtolower($message));
```

The above code was created to replace some special chars with normal ones but no matter which $nachricht (= $message) I put in, it always gives back an empty string!

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I Changed it to:

```
//Chars to be replaced

$suchmuster[0] = '/ /';
$suchmuster[1] = '/./';
$suchmuster[2] = '/,/';
$suchmuster[3] = '/-/';
$suchmuster[4] = '/_/';

//Replaces

$ersetzungen[0] = '';
$ersetzungen[1] = '';
$ersetzungen[2] = '';
$ersetzungen[3] = '';
$ersetzungen[4] = '';

$newmessage = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', strtolower($message));

$newmessage = preg_replace($suchmuster, $ersetzungen, $newmessage);
```

It still gives back an empty string.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`. Except `/ô/` none of your $suchmusters are valid regexps. If the charset is Latin-1, consider `str_replace` or `strtr` instead.

Comment: You know you can assign an array like this: `$suchmuster = array('á', 'à', 'â', /* etc. */);`

Comment: If you want just get rid of the diacritics, you can also use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) like `iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string)`.

Comment: Thank you.
error_reporting doesn't return anything.

It doesn't work even if I put every char to be replaced in "/ /"

Comment: Marc Korpel, thank you I found this a few seconds ago. I also don't want any special chars like "-" or "_" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using several patterns, you can also combine the pattern to:

```
$nachrichtneu = preg_replace('/[,.\s_-]/', '', $nachrichtneu);
```

And `strtolower` will not convert `Á` and the like to `á`. First do the `iconv` conversion, then the `strtolower`.

Comment: @NicoEnking And the reason you got back an empty string is explained by Kaii in their answer.

Comment: @HamZa Isn't escaping the dot necessary to prevent it matching every character?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel In a character class, the dot loses it's meaning, so it becomes a literal dot characters Which means it's redundant to escape it. [See this demo](http://regex101.com/r/nM9yH8). The same goes for a hyphen at the begin or end of a character class. [See this demo](http://regex101.com/r/fK6yS1).

Comment: @HamZa I just tested this myself, too. Thanks for the links to regex101.com, I didn't know that site and it looks very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your updated question:

Regular expressions use special control characters. In your case it is `/./` which causes your result to be empty. `.` means "any character" in regex, so you are replacing *each and every character* with nothing.

use `preg_quote()` to escape special characters in regular expressions. Example: `$xy = '/' . preg_quote('.') . '/';`

But you can do this much simpler without using regular expressions, like:

```
$replaces = array(
    '.' => '',
    ',' => '',
    // ...
);
$message = str_replace(array_keys($replaces), array_values($replaces), $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code through

```
$suchmuster = array();
$suchmuster[0] = "/á/";
$suchmuster[1] = "/à/";
```

...

Comment: I have updated my code but it still doesnt work (See my edit above)